# Trying to display the current month as a specific letter in an Access expression

Tags: ms-access

I need to make the default value for a certain field in Access be a certain letter representing the current month. For example, the month of January displays "A" the month of February displays "B" etc.

What I have now is:

```
=(Month(Now()),"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L")
```

Comment: You are correct, I have that in the Default Value property of a field and I don't even get a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the table in Design View and setting the `Default Value` property of the field in question to

```
=Chr(Asc("A")+Month(Date())-1)
```